# Can't see any effect of `asyncio.Transport.write()`

Tags: python-3.6, python-asyncio

I am trying to craft a simple homebrew localhost TCP server using asyncio (it's only Python 3.6.9, since I only have a LTS Ubuntu on this machine):

```py
import asyncio
import socket
import urllib.parse
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from io import BytesIO

class HTTPRequest(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request_text):
        self.rfile = BytesIO(request_text)
        self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
        self.error_code = self.error_message = None
        self.parse_request()
        rpc_request = urllib.parse.urlparse(self.path)
        self.endpoint = rpc_request.path
        self.query = urllib.parse.parse_qs(rpc_request.query)

    def send_error(self, code, message):
        self.error_code = code
        self.error_message = message


class Srv(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, address=('127.0.0.1', 12345), family=socket.AF_INET, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop=None):
        self._address = address
        self._family = family
        self._loop = loop if loop is not None else asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._server = None

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self._transport = transport

    def data_received(self, data):
        request = HTTPRequest(data)
        print("\tQuery:", request.query)
        self._transport.write(b'Hi!')
        self._transport.close()

    def eof_received(self):
        pass

    def factory(self):
        return self

    async def run(self):
        sock = socket.socket(family=self._family)
        sock.bind(self._address)
        sock.listen()
        if self._family == socket.AF_UNIX:
            self._server = await self._loop.create_unix_server(protocol_factory=self.factory, sock=sock)
        else:
            self._server = await self._loop.create_server(protocol_factory=self.factory, sock=sock, family=self._family)
        self._running = True

omg = Srv()

async def wat():
    await omg.run()
    await omg._server.wait_closed()

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(wat())
except:
    omg._server.close()
```

It seems to startup and even receive data:

```
$ python3 0_o.py 
    Query: {'data': ['"abcd"']}
    Query: {'data': ['"abcd"']}
```

(the prints are done from `Srv.data_received`), but curl says it receives no response from it:

```
$ curl '127.0.0.1:12345/query?data="abcd"'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
$ curl '127.0.0.1:12345/query?data="abcd"'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

From my perspective, I've reimplemented everything from echo server examples in python's stdlib documentation but apparently `write()` and `close()` inside `data_received()` don't seem to produce any effect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only problem with your code is that you're not emitting a proper HTTP response, but just the string "Hi". For example, running your code unchanged and connecting it wit `nc` results in the following:

```
$ nc localhost 12345
GET / HTTP/1.0
Hi!
```

Note not only the absence of a proper response, but the fact that the server didn't even wait for the client to complete the request. Instead, it immediately printed an ill-formed response.

Connecting with `curl` results in the following output:

```
$ curl http://localhost:12345/
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
```

"HTTP/0.9" refers to an ancient version of the HTTP protocol where the status line was optional. This response is rejected by curl, but Wget will accept it:

```
$ wget -qO- http://localhost:12345/
Hi!
```

Instead of attempting to implement HTTP manually, you can look into a library that does it for you, such as [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/).

Comment: I've changed the response into `self._transport.writelines([b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK', b'Content-Type: application/json', b'Content-Length: 15', b'{"hi": "there"}'])`, but still no nothing. :/

Comment: @bipll You didn't include the newlines. Please don't try to reimplement HTTP yourself, use aiohttp or equivalent library.

Comment: Ok, newlines seemingly helped, thank you. I'm not reimplementing HTTP, I'm trying to squeeze any output from my script.

Comment: @bipll Manually printing HTTP headers _is_ reimplementing HTTP, but if it works for you...